# Android Emulator Keyboard not displaying

Tags: android

Just installed the android sdk on my macbook pro. I created a virtual device, allotted 50mb worth of memory in android 3.0. I ran the emulator, and Android_ displays on the left, but the keyboard interface does not display on the right. I have hw.keyboard.lid enabled. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: What happens if you disable hw.keyboard.lid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or num pad <kbd>7</kbd> to enable an onscreen keyboard within the OS.  I don't think the 3.0 emulator has an equivalent keyboard interface the way the others do.

Answer (score 62):

This is how to make emulator to show soft keyboard:

Device settings > Language and Input > Default > Hardware (Physical Keyboard) > set to `Off`.

Comment: Click on Default then Hardware window will appear.

Answer (score 23):

You can also issue a command from the keyboard. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

e.g.

Android  ==   PC Keyboard

Back Key == ESC

Menu     == Page-up

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

the link is not there any more. there are more other descriptive answers here

[Android emulator doesn't take keyboard input - SDK tools rev 20](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11235370/319058)

Comment: The link is broken now.

Answer (score 5):

I just came across this problem and solved it - the default keyboard setting in the 3.0 image is set to the Japanese IME (which I'm assuming doesn't work landscape). Simply go into the settings and change it to the Android keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me: I enable the "Hardware Keyboard Present" in the AVD definition. When the AVD boots up, the virtual keyboard doesn't come up in the device, but the computer's keyboard works. I then go to Settings -> Language and Input -> Keyboard and input methods -> Default. Here, I switch off the Hardware (Physical Keyboard) option. Now, both the virtual keyboard as well as the computer keyboard works -- best of both worlds.

But, as user850688 said, you have to do this everytime you boot up the AVD. If you don't want to do that, switch off the Hardware Keyboard Present setting in the AVD and you will always have the virtual keyboard, but you cannot use the computer keyboard at all.

Answer (score 3):

yes, ctrl+f11 and num-7 bring up the soft keyboard. useful, but not as convenient for testing as the old side/emulator keyboard.

In the Android 3.0 SDK using v11 or higher a side-keyboard is apparently no longer available by default, presumably to better emulate that the devices are all touch-screens. An AVD based on the default WVGA800 tablet skin and any AVD based on a custom screen size will not have a side emulator keyboard for you to use, and I couldn't find which setting might turn it on. However...

I was able to get a side-keyboard (very very handy for dev+testing) by downloading some older skins from http://teavuihuang.com/android/ and creating AVDs based on these. Somehow this enables the emulator keyboard, through some file or setting which the AVD editor doesn't make available. The window sizes and emulator keyboard placement don't exactly line up, but it beats the heck out of nothing.

Seems like Google should have documented all of these intricacies at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html, but they haven't.

Comment: It's ok to try to better emulate touch screen only devices, but what about the home and back button? I found out the back button functionality can be obtained by pressing the esc key, but what about the home button?

Comment: Home button is still the "Home" button on your PC's keyboard! :)

Answer (score 3):

Just change AVD Device Features. You selected a specific Resolution eg. 240 X 360. Choose QVGA instead. Keyboard appears.

Answer (score 3):

On the newer Android versions, you won't find it the AVD settings, you simply need to load the emulator normally and go to the Settings app, there you can choose to NOT use the hardware keyboard of your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,If you enter manual resolution in AVD it will not show keyboard just select any default resolution keyboard will start showing up

Comment: the default resolution wxga does not show the keyboard- which is what i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will be helpful, but in Android 4.0, even if you have the hardware keyboard emulation enabled, you can pull down the system menu at the top of the screen, and it should give you to option to turn the hardware keyboard off, enabling the virtual keyboard again. Curiously, I found that hardware keyboard emulation still works - best of both worlds!

Comment: This works well, but it seems to reset each time the emulator is reboot. does this happen with you.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with that one, @user850688 - since I posted this answer, we've found the emulator slow and unstable enough that we tend to debug with real devices.

Answer (score 0):

you may try do this :
change default skin to with dynamic hardware controls  when you edit emulates
hopes to help you