# Why did keyboard input stop working in Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation

Recently upgraded my Android SDK install to r20 and now keyboard input seem to have stopped working with both existing and new AVDs.

Everything was working fine prior to the upgrade.

Does anyone know what would have caused this? (I'm using ubuntu 12.04 x64).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding "Keyboard Support" to the AVD within the AVD-Manager and changing the value to "true".

Comment: in my case, change the value to "yes"

Comment: This question contains more detailed information in case anyone is interested: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235370/android-emulator-doesnt-take-keyboard-input-sdk-tools-rev-20

Answer (score 5):

Turns out its [a change in the default settings](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30929) for the emulator in r20 of the Android SDK.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to enable the keyboard for your android virtual device via command line, edit `~/.android/avd/[YOUR_AVD].avd/config.ini` and add this to the file:

```
hw.keyboard=yes
```

Restart your AVD and you should be in business.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable the keyboard for your android virtual device via command line, edit~/.android/avd/[YOUR_AVD].avd/config.ini and add this to the file:
hw.keyboard=yes
Restart your AVD and you should be in business.

Or, go to following path(in my case mukesh is user):
mukesh/.android/avd/[YOUR_AVD].avd/config.ini and **add this line
hw.keyboard=yes**

You can learn more about this from my blog [Here](http://mukeshyadav4u.blogspot.in/2012/08/keyboard-input-stop-working-in-android.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a property to your AVD to enable keyboard support.

1. In Eclipse go to Window > Android Virtual Device Manager
2. Select your AVD
3. Click Edit...
4. In the Hardware section click New..
5. Property: Keyboard Support
6. Click OK
7. Change the value for Keyboard Support to "yes"
8. Click Edit AVD
9. Select your AVD
10. Click Start...