# How to type in Android Emulator using PC-Keyboard

Tags: android, android-emulator

I can not type in Emulator using PC-Keyboard.

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Go to windows-> Avd Manager . Select your AVD and edit it and add keyboard support under Hardware section . Make its boolean value true and Enjoy typing with PC's keyboard.

Comment: that's fine, but then the soft keyboard never shows. so w are stuck between typing on the softkeyboard, or typing on the hard keyboard and never showing the soft keyboard.

Comment: In Android Studio 3.0+, it is in tools>Android>AVD Manager

Answer (score 20):

For those who are using Android Studio.

1. Open Android Virtual Device Manager.
2. Click the '**Pencil icon**' align with the selected Emulator.
3. (A dialog will popup) Select <kbd>Show Advance Settings</kbd> button.
4. Find '**Enable Keyboard Input**' and ensure it's selected.
   [image]

5 Finally Click '**Finish**' and you're done!

Answer (score 9):

Open `AVD Manager` > Click on your target AVD > Edit > Hardware > new > Key board Support > Ok > make it yes > and try now

Answer (score 8):

Android Studio -> Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager -> Will show list of Virtual devices
Edit(pencil icon) of device you want to update settings ->Show Advanced Settings  -> Keyboard -> Check Enable Keyboard Input ->Finish.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check out from the below link: -

[Android emulator doesn't take keyboard input - SDK tools rev 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235370/android-emulator-doesnt-take-keyboard-input-sdk-tools-rev-20)

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23333/how-can-i-use-my-pcs-keyboard-on-the-android-emulator

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio > AVD Manager > Edit > Show Advanced Settings > Enable Keyboard input > Finish