# Cannot type from keyboard (hardware) in AVD (emulator) after updating ADT

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have just updated to ADT 20 and the newest of SDK, but since then dunno why I cannot type from keyboard (hardware) in AVD (emulator).

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235370/android-emulator-doesnt-take-keyboard-input-sdk-tools-rev-20

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In your Eclipse IDE, go to the **AVD Manager** and select your emulator device.

Click on **Edit** to edit the properties of this device.

In the **Hardware** section, click on **New**.

In the **Property** drop-down list, select **Keyboard Support** and press **OK**.

This add the property in your list of hardware but has a value "no" by default.

Click on the value column and change it to **"yes"**.

Click on **"Edit AVD"** once again to save your changes.

This will add a property **hw.keyboard=yes in config.ini** file for the AVD and now your emulator will support input form the keyboard.

Comment: While these instructions seem to work most of the time, I'm having issues (on OSX) where I can add the keyboard, but setting it to "Yes" doesn't stick.

Comment: @LuckyLuke : Could you kindly elaborate your `issues` in a question and send the link to me ? I would do my best to be of any help.

Comment: I already found the solution, this seems to be a bug in the AVD manager. After adding keyboard support and setting it to yes, one has to click on any other field in the list, and then it will actually work.

Comment: Great answer, because you did not only show how to use the AVD Manager, but gave the possibility to change directly the option at the `config.ini` file. +1

Answer (score 2):

Edit the device and add Keyboard Support.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a skin, check the `hardware.ini` that have `hw.keyboard = yes`