# Android emulator soft keyboard input disabled

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new to android apps.  I am moving an app from iPhone to Android.  If I get focus in an input field the soft keyboard pops up normally.  However, when I press the keys I do not get the information in the input field.  I have followed insructions here that suggest I go to the AVD Manager and edit the h/w for the keyboard adding keyboard support.  That does not solve my problem.

The AVD details for the keyboard are as follows:
     CPU/ABI: ARM(armeabi-v7a)
     Target: Android 4.1 - API l\Level 16
     Skin:  WVGA800
     hw/lcd/density: 240
     hw.keyboard.lid: yes
     hw.keyboard: yes

Any help is appreciated.

Howard (howard@flickitt.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing the soft keyboard appear it's because hw.keyboard isn't actually set to yes.  Can you check config.ini directly?  You've probably seen this but here's more detailed instructions.

[Android emulator doesn't take keyboard input - SDK tools rev 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235370/android-emulator-doesnt-take-keyboard-input-sdk-tools-rev-20/11252510)