# Eclipse Android Emulator - Keyboard not working

Tags: android, eclipse, keyboard, adt

I just updated to the latest SDK version 16 created a new version of an AVD using the latest version of the API (16) and my hardware keyboard doesn't work anymore on the emulator (even my other avd using an older version of the sdk).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Similar emulator keyboard issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235370/android-emulator-doesnt-take-keyboard-input-sdk-tools-rev-20

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go into the config.ini and added the line for the keyboard support i have to do this for my others avd devices as well to make them all work!

Add: `hw.keyboard=yes`

To: `~/.android/avd/<emulator-device-name>.avd/config.ini`

Answer (score 46):

Do you have "Keyboard Support" hardware property set to "yes" for your AVD?
Last time I updated Android SDK etc. the process trashed my adb configuration. So maybe it influenced your other emulator as well.

Comment: AVD Manager (eclipse) -> Edit -> Hardware list -> New

Comment: ok i will give a look yes it it messed up my older avd as well thanks!

Comment: ok a solved it but another way: i went into the config.ini and added the line for the keyboard support i have to do this for my others devices as well then... thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Ok your trick is doing the same thing so good answer :) thanks again !

Comment: @JeromeAnsia You should re-post your config.ini comment as a separate answer. You can answer your own questions.

Answer (score 10):

Go to AVD Manager > select AVD > Edit > in Hardware section press New > select Keyboard Support > press Ok > change it's value to Yes. That's it.

Comment: Please go to New > check for Keyboard lid support if it's set to "No" change it to "Yes".

Answer (score 2):

Go to eclipse's List(which is display on top) select:

1. Window
2. select AVD Manager
3. now Select AVD from next Created Window
4. go to Edit(from right side window)
5. now in hardware selection menu
6. support Keyboard
7. select ok
8. now click on selected keyboard
9. select yes from list