# Android emulator doesn't take keyboard input on custom AVD skins- SDK tools rev 20.0.1

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android emulator doesn’t take keyboard input - SDK tools rev 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235370/android-emulator-doesnt-take-keyboard-input-sdk-tools-rev-20)

For anyone who is using custom AVD skins and SDK tools rev 20, how do you get keyboard access to work?

The solution discussed in [Android emulator doesn't take keyboard input - SDK tools rev 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235370/android-emulator-doesnt-take-keyboard-input-sdk-tools-rev-20) only works for the fugly pixel hogging default skin (WVGA800).

Been using "Google Android Emulator Skins for Nexus S and Nexus One" found here:

http://heikobehrens.net/2011/03/15/android-skins/

I tried to edit the AVD config.ini by adding hw.keyboard = true, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there is a `hardware.ini` file in each of the skin's folder (for example `NEXUS-S`) that specify `hw.keyboard=no`. You can modify this line to enable the keyboard in the AVD that is based on the skin. There is also `hw.dPad=yes` if you wish to use the arrow-keys.

Comment: +100 (16 hours from now): Ouch there goes 20%-ish of my points but hopefully your answer will help others out who went through my same plight. Tried it out and it works. Thanks.

Comment: An exemplary answer indeed. However the description of bounty should be "One of the answers is exemplary and deserves an award".

Answer (score 0):

From Eclipse, Go to AVD Mananger.
Select the particular AVD and click on Edit
Go to the Hardware section, click on New.
Select the Property Name : Keyboard Support
By default, it is added with a value of 'no'. Just click on the value column and change it to 'yes'.
Click on Edit AVD again.
This will add a property hw.keyboard=yes in config.ini file for the AVD.

[Android emulator doesn't take keyboard input - SDK tools rev 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235370/android-emulator-doesnt-take-keyboard-input-sdk-tools-rev-20)

Hope this it helps

Comment: -1 This was not helpful. All you did was reference another Stack Overflow thread I had already referenced. Are you running the emulator with a  custom AVD skin?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the "custom AVD skin" part, but I found this thread from a google search and this was the exact answer I was looking for because I was using the default WVGA800 skin and still didn't have hardware support until I did what you described.  Perhaps call that out in your answer.

Comment: yeah i have to give -1 to this answer because it is clearly mentioned in the title of the question that keyboard is not working in the custom AVD skins.This answer is helpful for the default avd provided by the android.