# Emulator keyboard input in Linux

Tags: android, keyboard, emulation

After updating SDK tools rev to 20, Android emulator doesn't take keyboard input from my desktop keyboard. When press a key of the desktop keyboard, the emulator will dead and I have to kill its process.

Android emulator also didn't take keyboard input from emulator own keyboard. But I have fixed this by following the steps in [Android emulator doesn't take keyboard input - SDK tools rev 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235370/android-emulator-doesnt-take-keyboard-input-sdk-tools-rev-20).

Does anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

while creating/edit avd you need to mention the keyboard support.

[image]

Comment: I have done what you said. This solution works on my windows desktop; but not works on my linux desktop.

Comment: Actually yesterday my pal faced this issues in Linux and I solved with same what I said in this answer. it will work fine in linux also. can you show your avd details that your are using in linux.

Comment: hw.lcd.density=160
sdcard.size=256M
skin.name=HVGA
skin.path=platforms/android-8/skins/HVGA
hw.cpu.arch=arm
abi.type=armeabi
hw.keyboard=yes
image.sysdir.2=platforms/android-8/images/
image.sysdir.1=add-ons/addon_google_apis_google_inc_8/images/

Answer (score 0):

```
Open Android Virtual Device Manager 
Select Your AVD 
Edit
Hardware -> New (Open Property Window)
Select Keyboard Support and Click on Ok
Now Make it True
```

[image]

Comment: I have done what you said. This solution works on my windows desktop; but not works on my linux desktop.

Answer (score 0):

> An Avd manager ,  select you Emulator (Right side)---> Edit--->
>   Hardware(right side) ---> new---> property  ---> Keyboardsupport -->
>   yes

Comment: I have done what you said. This solution works on my windows desktop; but not works on my linux desktop.