# My Android Emulator is Korean

Tags: android

My Android SDK emulator seems to be in Korean.  The language setting in the actual Android OS for the AVD is US English, but the on-screen keyboard is still in Korean. I've created new AVDs and they are still Korean.

Comment: Well, the brute force solution will most likely work: rm -rf the sdk, eclipse, and all that, and start over.

Comment: @jeffamaphone That might help- I'm wondering if I downloaded a Korean image for android, or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by destroying that AVD and creating a new one.  The old AVD was targeting "Android 2.2" (API Level 8).  I created a duplicate which targeted "Google APIs (Google Inc.)" (API Level 8) and everything is now in english.

I'm guessing that I had installed a *Korean* AVD image from Samsung that had the generic english name "Android 2.2".

Also- the keyboard input was solved by upgrading to the SDK Version 21 as per [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235370/android-emulator-doesnt-take-keyboard-input-sdk-tools-rev-20)