# Usb external keyboard can't used on emulator android

Tags: java, android

I have numeric external keyboard USB, but it's not detected in android emulator. How to use it? Thanks before

Comment: Check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11252510/1832221

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse - try following

1.Eclipse -> Window menu -> AVD Manager

2.Select virtual device -> Edit

3.Select "Hardware Keyboard present" -> OK

Regards

Comment: I was try it, but my USB external keyboard not detected.