# How to show applist in android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, button, emulation, softkeys

I have been searching for button to show app listing in android emulator.In devices usually its button left to home button.In android emulator short keys list this button is listed as `shift + f2` ,butt pressing it opens the theam screen **.Is there any way to get applist button?**

Android N developer preview has multiwindow capability .But I think it is shown by pressing this applist button. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: It doest show menu button that shows all app grid ?

Comment: @AmitVaghela I think it show app grid in versions before lolipop.In my emulator it is showing menu.Any other way to show app grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can use **keyboard keys** if your emulator buttons are not working correctly :

> ### Emulated Device        --->    Key    Keyboard Key
>
> Home                   --->    HOME
>
> Menu (left softkey)    --->    F2 or Page-up button
>
> Star (right softkey)   --->    Shift-F2 or Page Down
>
> Back ---> ESC

Please check [Keyboard Commands](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/help/emulator.html#KeyMapping)

If you want to modify device hardware buttons than

go to

**tools --> android --> android device monitor ---> windows ---> android virtual device manager ---> device defination(tab) ---> change setting in buttons**

for more detail check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235370/android-emulator-doesnt-take-keyboard-input-sdk-tools-rev-20) answer.

Comment: Is your problem solved ? @user2217535

Comment: Yes my problem solved ,The soft keys are not showing because i am using non nexus devices when i start it with nexus devices its all start workging.