# In Android Emulator avd change settings to get non us layout of hardware keyboard

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Installed AndroidStudio 2.3, created a new virtual device having advanced setting **hw.keyboard=true**

Now I can use my PC keyboard to type text. Unfortunately **I cannot find a way to change the keyboard layout from US-Style to match my german PC Keyboard.** 
Especially typing in some symbols like e.g. "@" seems quite problematic (which would be `<Alt-Gr> + <q>` for a German layout).

Searching for answers all information I find is only about activating hw.keyboard (e.g. [Android emulator doesn't take keyboard input - SDK tools rev 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235370/android-emulator-doesnt-take-keyboard-input-sdk-tools-rev-20) ) - which is not my problem.

**My workaround:** 
I installed [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) in the emulation and with that I installed [Hacker's Keyboard](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=hacker&fdid=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard). OK now I can use the soft-keyboard within the emulation but still would like to use my normal pc-keybaord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way is to create a keyboard char map file (***.kcm**) and start the emulator via the command line.

See this [documentation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/master/docs/ANDROID-KEYBOARD-EMULATION.TXT) for details.

Here is a small extract from my current map file to map the key `z` to `y` and vice versa:

```
#keycode        display     number      base        caps        fn          caps_fn
Y               'Z'         'z'         'z'         'Z'         'z'         'Z'
Z               'y'         'y'         'y'         'Y'         'y'         'Y'
```

To use the charmap file (*.kcm) start the emulator with:

```
$ ./emulator -avd [AVD_DEVICE] -charmap /path/to/quertz.kcm
```

All available keycodes can be found in the source from the [emulator](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/master/android/skin/charmap.c).

Answer (score 1):

You can change Keyboard Layout in the Settings (Settings > System > Language) like on an actual Android Device when you run the Emulator, however this is not perfect, it seems not working for @,€, etc ...

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others

Comment: @Agilanbu: Wondering: *what* other keywords could it be? 
I feel your answer is still changing language only inside emulation, not allowing me to use my hardware USB PC Keyboard of my host, which is running the emulation. (currently I cannot verify it)