# Problems with displaying the built-in keypad of android emulator

Tags: android, emulation, virtual, keypad

I'm a little bit freshman in Android development so the some reasons may be sound incorrect.

I have been faced with a problem that the virtual keyboard is not displayed when I run the emulator for any created AVD with the varied parameters but it appears one of the following messages just without the expected keypad:

1. "Hardware keyboard not enabled in AVD. Use on screen keyboard" (With deselected checkbox "Hardware keyboard present").
2. "Hardware Keyboard. Use your physical keyboard to provide input" (With selected checkbox "Hardware keyboard present").

Also I played around the config.ini with the flags hw.keyboard, hw.keyboard.lid, hw.touchScreen but nothing couldn't help me.

The point of my question is how to get the most common view in the right side of emulator window like [this](http://www4.picturepush.com/photo/a/5553447/img/5553447.jpg).

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812064/android-emulator-keyboard-not-displaying

Comment: Yes, I saw this topic but in my case these shortcuts just change orientation Portrait<->Landscape. For details, look this case of screen I have: [Absence of Emulator Keypad and some buttons](http://radikal.ru/F/s52.radikal.ru/i138/1304/6c/4285e0f48abb.png.html). My brain is blown what happened and what should I do to be in fly:)?

Answer (score 0):

So, currently I have resolved my issue. All previous answers did not follow my question perhaps due to unclear explanation from my side.

So, to clarify this question, before I give an answer, the main point was: **I meant that there was absent not hardware or software keyboard but the emulator own skin keyboard and couple of another buttons.** I guess, my AVD Manager makes incorrect construction of AVD. It's the talk of the special **config.ini** file that contains two abnormal parameters:

> skin.name=320x480
>
> skin.path=320x480

After I changed it, for example, to

> skin.name=HVGA
>
> skin.path=platforms\android-XX\skins\HVGA

where XX means any version within described path to skin in Android SDK folder,

all skins are applied properly and emulator look better.

Unfortunately, I still have an issue with understanding. Why after the proper installation and configuration of dev. environment the AVD Manager formats **config.ini** file incorrectly with parameters **hw.dPad=no**, **hw.trackBall=no** by default and **skin.name** and **skin.path** set to the wrong values.