# Emulator not displaying keyboard

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. Although I have titled the question differently, my primary question is whether the AVD/Emulator supposed to show the keyboard? I am using Eclipse. If yes, is there any specific setting that needs to be done? I am only doing my first android app and my emulator doesnt show the keyboard.

Comment: [Android Emulator Keyboard not displaying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812064/android-emulator-keyboard-not-displaying)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your AVD, add "Keyboard Support" and change the value to no.

Restart your AVD making sure that you wipe user data. Your keyboard will popup now.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10239169/1405983) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235370/android-emulator-doesnt-take-keyboard-input-sdk-tools-rev-20).

Comment: Last answer in the 1st link (the one with the solution in the emulator itself) worked for me.

Comment: Hmm congrats buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

Just go to AVD manager in eclipse. Click Edit on current AVD after that just check Hardware Keyboard Present. Relaunch AVD and check.